# Issue with basic spring dependency injection where there is no setter just a getter

Tags: java, spring, dependencies, code-injection, setter

I have a scenario where I need to inject values to the Arraylist in a class that does not have the setter I believe in this scenario I need to do a get on the list in the POC class and then do a add:

```
public class POC {
  private  ArrayList<String> beheaviour=new ArrayList<String>();

  public ArrayList<String> getBeheaviour() {
    return beheaviour;
  }
}
```

Here is the xml mapping code :

```
<bean id="poc" class="outBoundocument.factory.POC">
  <property name="beheaviour">
    <list>
      <value>temp1</value>
      <value>temp2</value>
      <value>temp3</value>
      <value>temp4</value>
      <value>temp5</value>
    </list>
  </property>   
</bean>
```

the following code returns :

Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'beheaviour' of bean class [outBoundocument.factory.POC]: Bean property 'beheaviour' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

I have no control over the POC class as its a external vendor provided class and I cant do a constructor injection to it as the only way to add values to it is in the following way :

```
POC poc=new POC();
poc.getBeheaviour().add("some Stuff")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Spring will not be able to help you here (if you do not have access to the code). Spring only allows you to work with *closed-source* classes as beans if you define it in XML, which in turn makes it impossible to do attribute injection.

If you are not tied to Spring, you can do what you need with [Java Reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

---

***UPDATE***

Apologies, it seems you can autowire via XML. Have a look [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire).

Comment: Thanks Nico for your response yes unfortunately I cant autowire via xml hence we are requesting a change from the vendor side and having the methods deprecated.I wish spring would provide a implementation in the next version.Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

You could write a custom FactoryBean which adds the items.
Something like this in Java:

```
public class POCFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<POC> {
    private POC poc = new POC();    
    public void setBeheavior(List<String> items) {
        poc.getBehavior().addAll(items);
    }
    public POC getObject() {  
        return poc;
    }
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {   
        POC.class;
    }
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Corresponding XML:

```
<bean id="poc" class="some.package.POCFactoryBean">
  <property name="beheaviour">
    <list>
      <value>temp1</value>
      <value>temp2</value>
      <value>temp3</value>
      <value>temp4</value>
      <value>temp5</value>
    </list>
  </property>   
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks Pasi for your response the issue is I have multiple objects some thing around 250-260 for which I will have to create a factory class and then try to inject thru property injection in spring hence I am giving up this approach had this been mere 10 or 15 I would have jumped on it and implemented it.Thanks for the suggestion.